# Zorn's lemma, every set can be well-ordered

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, axiom-of-choice, well-orders

My task is to prove the well-ordering theorem:

> Every non empty set $X$ can be well-ordered

I want to do so in the following steps, which involve Zorn's lemma:

Step 1):

> Let $X$ be non empty and $\mathcal{P}=\{(Y,<_Y)| Y\subseteq X, \emptyset\neq Y~\text{and}~ <_Y ~ \text{is a well-ordering on Y}\}$. Show that $\mathcal{P}\neq\emptyset$

Proof:

Since $X\neq\emptyset$ it exists $x\in X$. Then $\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}$, because $\emptyset\neq\{x\}\subseteq X$ and $\{x\}$ can obviously be well-ordered.

So $\mathcal{P}\neq\emptyset$.

Step 2):

> Let $\leq$ be a partial order on $\mathcal{P}$ defined by:
>
> $(Y, <_Y)\leq (Z, <_Z)\Leftrightarrow Y\subseteq Z~\text{and for every $x,y\in Y$ holds:}~ (x<_Y y\Leftrightarrow x <_Z y)~\text{and for every $y\in Y$, $z\in Z-Y$ holds:}~ y <_Z z.$
>
> Show that $\mathcal{P}$ is ordered inductivly.

Proof:

We have to show that every linear ordered subset of $\mathcal{P}$ has an upper bound.

Let $\{(M_i, <_{M_i})_{i\in I}\}$ be a linear ordered subset of $\mathcal{P}$

Now I would set $S:=\bigcup_{i\in I} M_i$ with an order $<_S$ and show

$(M_i, <_{M_i})\leq (S,<_S)$ for every $i\in I$.

My problem is that I do not know how I can show that $(S,<_S)\in\mathcal{P}$ and in particular how to give an order on $S$.

Also I wonder if you can have a set $M$ with different orders in $\mathcal{P}$.

Like $M=\{x,y\}$ with the order $<$ and $<'$ where it is $x<'y$ and the other order $y<x$.
$M$ is well-orderd with regards to both orders.

And I feel like I would get a problem if such $M$ would occur in $S$.

Step 3):

> Is $(Y,<_Y)\in\mathcal{P}$ a maximal element regarding $\leq$, then is $Y=X$.

Proof:

First of all it is clear that $Y\subseteq X$.

So we just need to show $Y\supseteq X$.

Suppose the contrary and $Y\not\supseteq X$. Then there is $x\in X$ with $x\notin Y$.

Observe $(\underbrace{Y\cup\{x\}}_{:=Y'}, <_{Y'})$ where $u<_Y' v\Leftrightarrow u<_Y v$ if $u,v\in Y$ and $u<_Y x$ for every $u\in Y$.

Since $(Y,<_Y)$ is maximal we have:

$(Y',<_{Y'})\leq (Y,<_Y)$, but $Y'\not\subseteq Y$. Contradiction.

Step 4):

> Conclude the well-ordering theorem

With the lemma of Zorn we can now conclude, that $X$ can be well-ordered, since it is the maximal element of $\mathcal{P}$.

Besides the gap in step 2), is this correct?
How can I fix step 2) and provide an order on $S$?
What about my concern about equal sets with different orders?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 1 is simpler. The empty set is a well ordering of the empty set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But $\emptyset$ should not be an element of $\mathcal{P}$, since it only consists of nonempty subsets of $X$. Or not?

Comment: Yes, by why do you need that the subsets are not empty?

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is how the task is given. Also I would consider my proof of step 1) also pretty simple.

Comment: Well. Go to whomever gave you this task, and politely point out this unnecessary assumption. The empty set can be well ordered.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I might, but I am pretty sure the professor is aware of that.

Comment: You are certainly allowed to prove that every set can be well ordered, then note that this implies what you are asked to prove.  One of the parts of How to Solve It is prove something stronger.

Comment: @RossMillikan I do not understand your comment. Are you saying that I should prove that every set can be well ordered and not 'just' that every non empty set can be well ordered? I am more interested in comments on my proof-attempt and how I can fix the gaps, or where my mistakes are.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was suggesting.  The previous comments indicated that it was just as easy as the well-order of the empty set is trivial and it would avoid many qualifications in your work.  Step 1 becomes we want to prove some subset of $X$ can be well ordered.  $\emptyset \subset X, \emptyset$ can be well ordered.

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree that this makes step 1) trivial, but my proof of this part (which is also correct, isnt it?) is still very simple. So I do not understand why this is important to show the stronger result (or avoids many complications (qualifications?)). I am not saying that I do not understand why you should not proof the result for EVERY set, but I think that my questions are clear and I would prefer to get them answered. Also I do not see how this would help in fixing my proof of step 2). For me it seems that I would run into the same problem: How to define an order on $S$?